# Changing order in legend OR in plot, but not both

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
datat <- structure(list(Carga = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Outra", "88"), class = "factor"), 
    Categoria = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "G", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    Vagas = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ocupadas", "Autorizadas"), class = "factor"), 
    Cat.A.88 = c(26, 1, 30, 1, 18, 0, 57, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Carga", 
"Categoria", "Vagas", "Cat.A.88"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

and this plot:

```
ggplot(datat, aes(x=Carga, y=Cat.A.88, fill=Vagas)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') + ylab('Vagas') + xlab('Carga horária') + facet_grid(. ~ Categoria) + coord_flip()
```

The legend colours are in inverse order if compared with plot colours (plot have green before red, and legend have red before green). I want they appers in the same order. I tried add the parameter `order=-as.numeric(Vagas)` in `aes()`, but didn't changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
ggplot(datat, aes(x=Carga, y=Cat.A.88, fill=Vagas)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') + ylab('Vagas') + 
  xlab('Carga horária') + facet_grid(. ~ Categoria) + coord_flip() + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=T))
```